# Backbone.js & Marionette.js - Cannot access views from main app.js file

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I cant seem to access my Views from my main app file.  I'm new to backbone and marionette and I'v read through the documents but cannot find why its not working.  Any help or advise?

app.js

```
window.App = new Marionette.Application();

    App.addRegions({
        gameCriteria: "#game-criteria"
    });

    App.myRegion.show(myView);

});
```

myView.js

```
App.module("Views", function(Views, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {

   var GameCriteriaTab = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
       template: JST["game-criteria-tab"],

        regions: {
            rulesRegion: "#rules-region"
        },

        onShow: function() {
            this.rulesRegion.show(RulesView);
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

did you instatiate your view before calling show ? i am waiting for a code similar to that :

```
App.myRegion.show(new GameCriteriaTab ({
                                            model: new GameCriteriaModel()
                                         }));
```

can you provide us with the error in chrome console ?

Comment: Its just saying that my view is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do here. I'm assuming that you want to create an app called 'windowApp', and you are trying to display a view called 'GameCriteriaTab' inside a region called 'gameCriteria'. I'm refactoring your code to the following:-

```
windowApp = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

windowApp.addRegions({
    gameCriteria: "#game-criteria"
});

windowApp.GameCriteriaTab = Marionette.ItemView.extend({  //Defining the view
   template: " <include your template Id or className here> "
});     

windowApp.on("start",function(){
    var myView = new windowApp.GameCriteriaTab(); //You need to create an instance of the view if you want to render it in the page
    windowApp.gameCriteria.show(myView);  //Showing the view in the specified region
});

windowApp.start();  //This will run the marionette application
```

You cannot define any regions inside ItemView. Are you trying to create a nested view? In that case, a LayoutView would suit your needs, and you can add regions inside it. Just change the ItemView to a LayoutView then.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm doing.  But, what if the ItemView was in a separate file?  Called after app.js in the index.html head tag.  Also, window.App is being called because I'm attempting to have all my files JS to be available in the DOM.  My app is not called "windowApp"

Comment: In that case, structure your code in this manner:- view definition in myView.js, this line of code- 'windowApp.start()' in another file called appStart.js, and the rest of the code in app.js. Then you can include these files in your index.html in the following sequence:- app.js, myView.js and appStart.js

Comment: Also if I change ItemView to LayoutView I get the following error:  Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined

Comment: Try Marionette.Layout.extend instead of Marionette.ItemView.

Comment: If I move the file structure it doesn't recognize App.GameCriteriaTab();

Comment: After changing to Layout.extend it console logs: Cannot read property 'isClosed' of undefined

Comment: Can you tell what file structure you used and the code inside the files?

Comment: Its as you advised: I put Marionette.Layout into a file called GameCriteriaTab.js.  app.js contains the region and App.on start function.  And another file called last contains the App.Start();  Called in the order of: app.js, GameCriteria.js, start.js

Comment: Check out this jsfiddle link:- http://jsfiddle.net/TDqkj/6/ Have you loaded all the libraries and dependencies in order?

Comment: @conor909 This would be of help to you- http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/03/22/managing-layouts-and-nested-views-with-backbone-marionette/    https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/wiki/Use-cases-for-the-different-views